# How do I redirect example.com to example.com/subdirectory?

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I’m trying to redirect `example.com` (and `example.com/`, `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/`) to `example.com/subdirectory`. I could do this easily using HTML but from what I read, it’s better to make a 301 redirect using Apache.

How can I do this using Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 301 redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /subdirectory/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a .htaccess file using the `RewriteRule` keyword. See [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more info on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> Note* This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.

Source: http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

Example usage would be

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://somewhere.com/directory [R=301,L]
```

I guess